# Can I define a variable in the middle of a body?

Tags: scheme, language-lawyer

When a `define` is not in the outermost level of the program, can the `define` occur in the middle of a body? For example:

```lisp
(define (f x)
  (display x)
  (define n 1)  ; <- Is this allowed?
  (+ n x))
```

Or must internal `define`s always occur at the beginning of a body? For example:

```lisp
(define (f x)
  (define n 1)  ; <-
  (display x)
  (+ n x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions have to be at the beginning of a function body. From Section 5.3.2 of [R<sup>7</sup>RS](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf):

> **5.3.2. Internal definitions**
> Definitions can occur at the beginning of a <body> (that
> is, the body of a `lambda`, `let`, `let*`, `letrec`, `letrec*`,
> `let-values`, `let*-values`, `let-syntax`, `letrec-syntax`,
> `parameterize`, `guard`, or `case-lambda`). Note that such a
> body might not be apparent until after expansion of other
> syntax. Such definitions are known as *internal definitions*
> as opposed to the global definitions described above.

Comment: Why does that section list "`lambda`, `let`, `let*`, ...", but not `define`?

Comment: Because `define` is just a shortcut for `lambda`.

Comment: `(define (func ...args) body)` is just short for `(define func (lambda (...args) body))`